# What does the word "lost" mean in the phrase "lost kingdom"

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

Any ideas on the meaning of the word "lost" in "lost kingdom"

Comment: Is there a full sentence that goes with that? A sentence or context could help to put forward an answer.

Comment: Welcome to ELL!  Please share what research you have already done, and what you found that confused you.  Did you look up "lost" in the dictionary and do you have some meanings that you think might fit?  What do you think the answer might be?  (Use the [Edit] button on your question and add details, please.)  Please read the "[Contributor's Guide to ELL](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4783/contributors-guide)" and [Details Please](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/details-please).  Keep contributing and welcome!

Answer (score 1):

More information about exactly what you are asking would help, but a "lost kingdom" can have two meanings.

There are real kingdoms which are known to have existed historically, but of which either there is no trace in the present and it is uncertain exactly where they were or there are  those with no contemporaneous written records and few if any artifacts. Much of what is known about King Arthur is speculation or written by chronicallers much later. His kingdom can be said to be [lost](https://www.pbs.org/wnet/secrets/king-arthurs-lost-kingdom-king-arthurs-lost-kingdom-about-the-film/4069/). Similarly [Guge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guge) in Tibet and [Punt](https://www.ancient-origins.net/ancient-places-africa/somalia-ancient-lost-kingdom-punt-finally-found-006893) in Somalia

"Lost Kingdom" is also a literary device for adventure story telling. Probably the most famous of which is [Shangri-La](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shangri-La) invented by James Hilton in his 1933 novel Lost Horizons.